# Moving .pdf as a raster freely without referencing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, pdf, move

If I import a .pdf as a new raster layer, but the referencing is off.

Is there a tool in QGIS to grab and hold on to the pdf so i can move it freely to my desired location without having to worry about referencing it correctly to my coordinate system?

Similar to grabbing a picture in windows word and dragging it around in the document with the courser.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am using QGIS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide that information in its body.  Tagging is useful too.

Comment: Instead of importing your raster directly, you could use it as a raster image marker on a point layer. Then you can grab and move the point with the move feature tool.